# Multiple Options in a single argument

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am working on a ticket system inside my bot. I would like to have: `-ticket new` or `-ticket close`. But I need to know how to have 2 different reactions to these commands. So when a player types `-ticket new <subject>`, it will open a new ticket send a logging message in my logging channel which states the subject of the ticket & mention my support team role. Or when a player types `-ticket close <subject>`, it will close an existing ticket & send a logging message in my logging channel which states the subject of the ticket.

I have tried
`exports.run(client, message, arg1, arg2, subject) => {
if (args.slice(1).join(''))`
or
`exports.run(client, message, arg1, arg2, subject) => {
if (args[1] === '')`

My current code

```
exports.run = (client, message, arg1, arg2, subject) => {
    let error = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setColor("RED")
    .setFooter("NebulaCraft")
    .setTimestamp()
    .setDescription("An error accoured please try again. If this reacours please contact support.")
    if (args.slice(1).join("new")) {
        let new1 = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor("GREEN")
        .setFooter("NebulaCraft")
        .setTimestamp()
        .setTitle('New Ticket')
        .addField('Author', message.author)
        .addField('Subject', `${subject}`)
        client.channels.get('539852428565282851').send(new1).catch(console.error)
        return (message.channel.send(error).catch(console.error))
    }
    if (args.slice(1).join("close")) {
        let close1 = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor("GREEN")
        .setFooter("NebulaCraft")
        .setTimestamp()
        .setTitle('Ticket Closed')
        .addField('Closed By', message.author)
        .addField('Subject', `${subject}`)
        client.channels.get('539852428565282851').send(close1).catch(console.error)
        return (message.channel.send(error).catch(console.error))
    }
}
```

I expect to get a code that creates 2 options for a single arg only. I would like to have it send 2 different messages for the 2 options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (args[0] === 'option1') {
    // Command specific here
} else if (args[0] === 'option2') {
    // Command specific here
} else if (args[0] === 'option3') {
    // Command specific here
} else {
    // If none of the options match
    // Command error specific here
}
```

This works perfectly fine!

Answer (score 1):

Keep the exports like they were before `exports.run(client, message, args) =>`
The final code should be:

```js
exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
    let error = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setColor("RED")
    .setFooter("NebulaCraft")
    .setTimestamp()
    .setDescription("An error accoured please try again. If this reacours please contact support.")
    if (args[0] === 'new') {
        let new1 = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor("GREEN")
        .setFooter("NebulaCraft")
        .setTimestamp()
        .setTitle('New Ticket')
        .addField('Author', message.author)
        .addField('Subject',  args.slice(1).join(' '))
        client.channels.get('539852428565282851').send(new1).catch(console.error)
        return (message.channel.send(error).catch(console.error))
    }
    if (args[0] === 'close') {
        let close1 = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor("GREEN")
        .setFooter("NebulaCraft")
        .setTimestamp()
        .setTitle('Ticket Closed')
        .addField('Closed By', message.author)
        .addField('Subject',  args.slice(1).join(' '))
        client.channels.get('539852428565282851').send(close1).catch(console.error)
        return (message.channel.send(error).catch(console.error))
    }
}
```